# Connecting Laptop to Monitor while it is switched on

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

Is it ok to connect a laptop to a monitor via a VGA cable while the laptop is on? Normally I shutdown my laptop before doing so - but is this necessary?

I am using Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's absolutely not necessary to turn off your laptop. Vga connections allow hot swap without any particular problems.